# Normalizing random in Java

Tags: java, random

Could someone point me to a normalized random function for Java? The regular random function, as I understand it, doesn't have the kind of behaviour that humans think of as random; however, I remember from my stat class that a normalized random function does.

This is for an autodidactic program that needs to randomly decide which question to display next.

Comment: What exactly do humans think of as "random"? The Java function seems random enough for picking a "random next question".

Comment: exactly how long ago was this stats class?

Comment: I think I agree with @Wormbo in that it seems that a random number generator with a uniform distribution might suit your needs here. Guess it depends on the specifics of your program though.

Comment: Umm, well, the random function can sometimes throw up the same question five times in a row, that kind of thing; it's still random (I know), but not what humans expect. I imagine what humans expect is that the list (in this case) would be randomly shuffled, then questions will be served from the list, removing the question as its presented, until it is completely empty. Then wash, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Shuffling is not always enough.  If you present the same set of questions twice, the question that appears last in the first pass could appear first in the second pass, so the user would see the same question twice in a row.

Comment: To shuffle a collection of questions see `Collections#shuffle(List)` or `Collections#shuffle(List,Random)`. As mentioned by @finnw, however, that may not be sufficient if you are doing multiple runs without a break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for random numbers that are "normally" distributed then see `java.util.Random#nextGaussian()`